# Data accuracy measurment

Tags: electrical-engineering, instrumentation

What is the meaning of sentence "Measured Data has 30 PPM accuracy"?
I want to know what is the meaning of PPM accuracy.

Comment: PPM is parts per million

Comment: Hi Sudharshan, welcome to engineering.SE.  Can you please add some context to this question?  Where did you see the statement that "measured data has 30 ppm accuracy"?  As you can see from the current answers, it is possible for this statement to have different meanings depending on context.

Answer (score 4):

ppm = parts per million, analogous to percent = parts per 100.

So 1 ppm error is equivalent to 0.0001 % error.

In the context of accuracy, it's, like percents, a dangerous unit to use, since it is not always clear whether it refers to a fraction of the maximum signal, to a fraction of the actual measured value, or to an absolute error.

For example: you measure the concentration of something with a device that can measure concentrations between 0 and 10000 ppm. A data point shows a concentration of 1000 ppm. The accuracy is stated to be 10 ppm. Now the reader has to figure out which of the following is meant:

- 10 ppm of full scale means that the value is 1000 +/- 0.1 ppm.
- 10 ppm of the actual value means that the value is 1000 +/- 0.01 ppm.
- 10 ppm absolute error means that the value is 1000 +/- 10 ppm.

Comment: lies, damned lies and statistics...

Answer (score 0):

PPM or *parts per million* is usually used to measure the concentration of a substance in a mixture, generally when the substance being measure is a small fraction of the total.

A common usage is for defining acceptable or safe levels of pollutants, toxins etc in water or air.

The most logical interpretation of the 30 PPM accuracy claim is that the device has an accuracy of +/- 30 PPM ie if it reads 100 PPM the true value lies in the range of 70 to 130 PPM.

It could be interpreted as a *range* of 30 PPM in which case the true figure would be 15 PPM plus or minus.

It is also possible that it could mean that the device can detect concentrations *above* 30 PPM which might be more likely in the case of something which gives an alarm when a certain threshold is reached.

Comment: While the question isn't completely clear, I believe this answer is incorrect.  Units of ppm are commonly used to refer to error in a measurement when the error is below the level of ~0.1% which is described in Han-Kwang's answer.